# Revoke claims/token from AD, via ADFS to RP

Tags: asp.net, wif, adfs, claims

We have a website, which our users access by getting an STS from ADFS. ADFS issues claims by checking the user's groups memberships in Active Directory. The website uses WIF to access claims and handle authentication.

Is there a way, when a user's AD data changes (e.g. they have all their group memberships removed), to have those changes reflected immediately (same session, at least from the user's PoV) in their claims for the RP? Currently, if we revoke membership in AD, that user's claims for the RP (in their current session) aren't affected. They have the same claims, and access, that they had before the revocation, until the user's ADFS session expires (which could be hours away).

> e.g. user U1 logs in to our website W1 via ADFS, browses round a bit, and then has his memberships cancelled in AD. We need U1 to be logged out of W1 automatically within a short time period (minutes). If not logged out, having their claimset in WIF reset to reflect their now-empty AD group memberships would also be acceptable.

Is this possible? All the documentation I can find seems to assume that the website itself (W1) knows when the user should have their session terminated - in our case W1 doesn't know, the "trigger" for session expiry (or at least claims amendment) will be from AD.

Answer (score 1):

Out the box - no.

Claims aren't dynamic - they are only created at logon.

The only way I can think of is for your app. to poll AD every now and then and if the  membership is removed, then do an application logout "under the hood".

The next time the user tries to do something, WIF will see that they don't have a session, will go to ADFS to login, ADFS will see that they are still logged in and access will be granted automatically i.e. the whole process will be transparent.

Because the use was logged in again, the claims will be updated and the membership will no longer be a claim.